# Rails 6 Auto delete posts from database every 24 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automation

is there a way to automatically delete posts/products/articles or anything created on a rails 6 app? I'm trying to build an online image repository that users can upload images that appear only for 24 hours and then get deleted.I have the posting and saving of the pictures/text through active storage and Postgres but i can't get it to get deleted automatically. I've read about whenever sidekiq and resque scheduler but i find it difficult to understand and make it work. i tried from some tutorials and reading the documentation but I'm still having trouble. Can anyone point me in the right direction or try to help me?

Comment: `whenever` gem to schedule a `destroy` call on your models through a `rake` task. In reality you should want to hide the images rather than destroy them, but that is a product decision.

Comment: i would like to destroy them since i dont want to cluter the server (hoping i will get many users) , i would like to make it no needing me. you know like built it deploy it and just take a look from time to time to see if everything is ok. i thought the whenever gem is only used in linux? right now im building in windows although i will deploy in a linux private server

Comment: The problem with the `whenever` gem is that it is probably not supported in production. Either you use rake tasks and run them via a worker, or like you said you learn how to use Sidekiq and Redis, which I have used in many apps in the past and works like a charm!

Comment: Is there any helpful tutorial on sidekiq? I've been watching and reading these days but I can't figure it out

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started what you should do is try some of this and then come back with a specific sidekiq question if you need help. Sidekiq is pretty good when you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options

1. The simplest one is creating a [rake task](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/02/ruby-rake/) and setting up a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to call this time every minute or something like that. If you call it every 24h you may end up with posts staying for up to 47h.
2. You can use [delayed jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) in two ways

   2.1 In an after_create callback, set a job to delete the post after 24 hours. Something like this `handle_asynchronously :in_the_future, run_at: Proc.new { 24.hours.from_now }`

   2.2 Using [delayed_job_recurring](https://github.com/amitree/delayed_job_recurring) gem to do the same thing in option one, but without the need of using cron

Edit: I would use option 2.1 since it's the simplest one and easier to maintain, the only downside is that it will create a job for every post, but that shouldn't be a problem even with a million posts a day

Comment: Is `delayed_job` actively maintained, there doesn't seem to be much activity on there in terms of commits at least.

Comment: It does seem pretty forgotten now that you mention it... Still, I've been using it in prodcution environments for years without issues, so... Not that bad, still wouldn't hurt to find something new

Comment: Yeah, I've used it quite a lot too, no problems so far...